# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined need it

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

need some help, trying deploy function on **Cloud Function for firebase** but send me some errors, cant find problem without line number.

Hi guys, need some help, trying deploy function on Cloud Function for firebase but send me some errors, cant find problem without line number.

> [debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcvhI.png)
>
> [config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDyc5.png)
>
> [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nABja.png)

```java
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const adminConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);

admin.initializeApp(adminConfig);

exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{followedUid}/{followerUid}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
      const followerUid = context.params.followerUid;
      const followedUid = context.params.followedUid;
      // If un-follow we exit the function.
      if (!change.after.val()) {
        return console.log('User ', followerUid, 'un-followed user', followedUid);
      }
      console.log('We have a new follower UID:', followerUid, 'for user:', followedUid);

      // Get the list of device notification tokens.
      const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
          .ref(`/users/${followedUid}/InstanceToken`).once('value');

      // Get the follower profile.
      const getFollowerProfilePromise = admin.auth().getUser(followerUid);

      // The snapshot to the user's tokens.
      let tokensSnapshot;

      // The array containing all the user's tokens.
      let tokens;

      const results = await Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getFollowerProfilePromise]);
      tokensSnapshot = results[0];
      const follower = results[1];

      // Check if there are any device tokens.
      if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
        return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
      }
      console.log('There are', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');
      console.log('Fetched follower profile', follower);

      // Notification details.
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: 'You have a new follower!',
          body: `${follower.displayName} is now following you.`,
          icon: follower.photoURL
        }
      };

      // Listing all tokens as an array.
      tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
      // Send notifications to all tokens.
      const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
      // For each message check if there was an error.
      const tokensToRemove = [];
      response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
          console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
          // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
          if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
            tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
          }
        }
      });
      return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
    });
```

```java
{
  "name": "fcm-notifications-functions",
  "description": "Send FCM notifications Firebase Functions sample",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~7.1.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "firebase": {
    "databaseURL": "https://touchfox-66c2c.firebaseio.com"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.13.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --max-warnings=0 .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

error:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: if (typeof context.params === 'undefined') {
       context.params = {};
    } Try to check params undefined first. Before object.keys line.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/528   This is similar issue. You need to update firebase-functions to 3.1 .

Comment: yes i did update to 3.3 and trying this if (typeof context.params === 'undefined') { context.params = {}; }  but same problem

Comment: There's one working around some gets to work is "Update node version to Latest with firebase cloud function too" to. Node.js 8 version often gets this type of error.

Comment: Node.js 8
"engines": {  "node": "8.12.0"},

Comment: Update node.js version to 10 and above, some people found out that this works.

Comment: yes i did, should i instal something or just adding code for index.js and package.json?

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue by upgrading your Node version to 10 as GaurangDhorda suggested?

Comment: can some one re code this for notification system?

Comment: @RendearSoft Please confirm if were you able to solve your original issue. If your original issue was solved, you should make a new post providing details on what you need and what is the exact problem you are facing.